# How do I get specific information from 'conda info'?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, conda

I'm trying to write a script that checks specific information of the conda that's installed on the user's computer.

For example, consider the call of `conda info` below. For my use, I just need the type of conda (miniforge3), the channel URLs, and the platform.

How would someone go about getting specific information from a data dump like this?

Is there a way to parse this data in a bash script?

If not, is there someway I can call something like `conda info.platform` and have it echo `osx-arm64`?

```
    higgsy@Higgsys-MBP Desktop % conda info

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/higgsy/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/higgsy/miniforge3/.condarc
                          /Users/higgsy/.condarc
          conda version : 4.12.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.13.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=12.5=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=arm64
       base environment : /Users/higgsy/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/higgsy/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /Users/higgsy/miniforge3/pkgs
                          /Users/higgsy/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/higgsy/miniforge3/envs
                          /Users/higgsy/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/4.12.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.13 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/12.5
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Please edit question and add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no com

Comment: @Cyrus I'm not quite sure what you mean but I did edit it a bit. Maybe that helps? I also separated the question to make it stand out a bit more.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Cyrus I think it's pretty straight forward. I've tried Googling info on this and haven't found anything. I come to StackOverflow as a last ditch effort. If you don't know the answer, that's fine. Neither do I. xD But, I think it's a pretty straight forward question.

Comment: @Cyrus, I see that you voted to close this question. I think this is a legitimate question. I can't find the answer to this. That's pretty toxic behavior.

Comment: @Higgsy What is the expected output?

Comment: @Hatless 'conda info' gives the correct output. My question is, is there a way to get one specific piece of information from that dump or do I need to always have the entire dump? For example, is there some special command like 'conda --platform info' or something? I'm trying to get specific info for use in a bash script.

Comment: @Hatless it's also frustrating that I haven't been able to find this answer and no one has really answered it (which is fine) but people are voting to close this question?! It's a legitimate question! When did SO become so toxic. It's bizarre.

Comment: @Hatless I'm not quite sure how to show that. I've typed random things into Terminal, if that's what you mean. I've even looked at the Conda website for the commands. I have an example of what I'm hoping to parse out in the question (the last sentence). I'm just trying to see if there's either some command I don't know about in conda or if there's a way to parse the data in a bash script.

Comment: It seems that https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/info.html#Output,%20Prompt,%20and%20Flow%20Control%20Options doesn't give the output you want. You could still use a `grep` & other ways to "cut" the info, like `sed`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, @Larme I'm not quite sure how to use those but I will look it up!

Comment: @Higgsy Use history and share the code you tried that failed. Then add or describe as vividly as possible the output you'd expect. From reading, it seems like you only want to display 3 lines but, what is `type of conda`? If you make the question and expected output clearer and share your efforts, I am sure answers will follow.

Comment: I don't use `conda`, but it seems that `conda list --show-channel-urls` might work. (I don't know the output though) `conda info --envs` too for the environment?

Comment: Per @Hatless earlier comment, something like `conda info | grep 'platform\|channel URLs'` could get you the platform and channel URLs, but the "type of conda"  is not really available in the output from `conda info`.  You might be able to parse some of the other fields in the output to infer the type of conda but that seems fragile to me.  Can you clarify the expected output?

Comment: @Larme Thanks again. Those commands give me info about the python packages installed. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @j_b Holy crap, man. You're a damn hero! I appreciate that! This is what I was looking for. It looks like I need to learn ```grep```

Comment: @Hatless j_b answered it.

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid parsing formatted output

It is better not to rely on processing formatted shell output. This particular output from Conda is meant for users to read, not to be programmatically parsed. As such, it is subject to change.

### Programmatic formats

#### JSON

Instead, one can obtain all the same information formatted as JSON with `conda info --json`. This will give even more information and may be overkill, but it will be reliably formatted. I would go this route if the processing is not happening in shell, but in a full-featured scripting language (e.g., Python, JavaScript).

#### YAML, with specific queries

Alternatively, the `conda config --show` command can query an arbitrary set of configuration values. For example, if you wanted just the platform, it goes by `subdir`:

```bash
> conda config --show subdir
subdir: osx-64
```

or both platform and channels:

```bash
> conda config --show subdir channels
subdir: osx-64
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

Note that this output is all valid YAML.

### Conda "type" is not a thing

The Conda configuration does not have a setting for the installer of origin. Moreover, all Conda installations can effectively be converted to another variant with a matter of package installs and adding settings to `.condarc`.

For example, I have an old Miniconda3 installation on a machine, but it is essentially a Mambaforge installation, since `conda-forge` channel is prioritized and `mamba` is installed. I'm not sure what you plan to do with such a classification, but it is not clearly defined.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've read online that only the Miniforge3 configuration works properly with Apple silicon. So, my goal was the ensure that version was installed. I've never messed with ```.condarc``` but I could try it out.

Comment: @Higgsy that's likely not reliable information. The landscape for **osx-arm64** support is rapidly evolving. Most commentary you'll find is probably from before Anaconda and Miniconda released native distributions. So, very unlikely you should care about how Conda was installed - just check the platform/subdir. But note that one can install **osx-64** on **osx-arm64**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help of @j_b and @Larme.

If you want to isolate something from `conda info`, you can pipe it into `grep` and `awk`.

For example, the example below finds the line with `platform` in it with grep and then removes `platform :`  with `awk` using `sub`

```
conda info | grep 'platform' | awk '{sub(/platform.:./,""); print}'
osx-arm64
```

Similarly, the `channel URLs` can be found the same way.

```
conda info | grep 'channel URLs' | awk '{sub(/channel.URLs.:./,""); print}'
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
```

Thanks again, @Larme and @j_b

Comment: You can get both `platform` and `channel URLs` values in a single awk command and avoid the pipe to grep:  `awk -F' : ' '{ if (/platform/ || /channel URLs/) {print $2} }'  < <(conda info)`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> conda info | mawk '_{exit}_+=!_<(NF=NF)' OFS= FS='^.+ platform[ :]+'
> ```

```
osx-arm64
```

Comment: This looks like Greek to me but it's much smaller than my solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Higgsy : replace the `_` each with something like `x` or `var1` , and read it again - it should make more sense - every row would be `NF` of 0 or 1 unless it's that platform row, then `NF == 2`, but once it hit that row, upon start to next row - the first condition would also be met, thus triggering the `exit` statement immediately (in case the input is very long)